# Trying to create a login for Admin/User PHP

Tags: php, mysql, forms, authentication, admin

I'm trying to create a log in for a user and admin from the same form, redirecting them to a certain page depending on if they are an admin or a user.

I have created a column in my db for admin and stated that admin = 1. I seem to be getting this error when entering the details for both my admin and user.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in
>   ...root\CheckLogin.php on line 31

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    // not logged in
}
?>

<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

// Query
global $dbh
$result= $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$myusername' AND password='$mypassword';");

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count = $result->rowCount();

// Determine if user is "user" or "admin"
$usertype = $dbh->query("SELECT admin FROM members WHERE username='$myusername';");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($usertype);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file 
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = '$username';
$_SESSION['password'] = '$password'; 
$_SESSION['admin'] = $row;

// Redirect to appropriate page depending on user rights. Indicator 0 for user, 1 for admin.
if ($_SESSION['admin'] == 1){
    header("location:Admin.php");
    }
else {
    header("location:SuccessLogin.php");
    }
$dbh = null;
}
else {
echo "";
}
?> 

<html>
<body>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<div class="lg-container">
<center><i>Wrong Username or Password</i></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: standard disclaimer (use mysqli, or pdo, etc..). But where is $dbh defined?  you have all the login info etc, but then refer to a global $dbh,that appears to not be defined/initialized, hence the error.

Comment: You're mixing `mysql_*` functions with PDO functions `rowCount()` you can't do that, so that's why you're getting the error. Pick one API, not two.

Comment: where is your connection or include connection tags

Answer (score 1):

Your should assign `mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");`  to `$dbh` like below:

```
$dbh = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
```

Pass too the connection variable to the `myslq_select_db`.

```
mysql_select_db("$db_name", $dbh)or die("cannot select DB");
```

Answer (score 1):

Complete code

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    // not logged in
}
?>

<?php
$host = "localhost"; // Host name 
$username = ""; // Mysql username 
$password = ""; // Mysql password 
$db_name = "test"; // Database name 
$tbl_name = "members"; // Table name 
// Connect to server and select databse.
$dbh=mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password,$db_name) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($dbh));

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername = $_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword = $_POST['mypassword'];

// To protect MySQL injection
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);


$result = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$myusername' AND password='$mypassword';");

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count = $result->num_row;

// Determine if user is "user" or "admin"
$usertype = $dbh->query("SELECT admin FROM members WHERE username='$myusername';");
$row = $usertype->fetch_row();

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if ($count == 1) {

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file 
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = '$username';
    $_SESSION['password'] = '$password';
    $_SESSION['admin'] = $row;

// Redirect to appropriate page depending on user rights. Indicator 0 for user, 1 for admin.
    if ($_SESSION['admin'] == 1) {
        header("location:Admin.php");
    } else {
        header("location:SuccessLogin.php");
    }
    $dbh = null;
} else {
    echo "";
}
?> 

<html>
    <body>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    <div class="lg-container">
        <center><i>Wrong Username or Password</i></center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've tried this, when i log in receive "Wrong Username or Password" even if they are correct along with this error.                               Notice: Undefined property: mysqli_result::$num_row in ...root\CheckLogin.php on line 31

Comment: Change `$count = $result->num_row;` to `$count = mysql_num_rows($result);` @user3489226 Using `num_row` on its own is invalid. Yet, this answer is using `mysqli_*` based functions and will not work at all. `fetch_row()` should be using `mysql_fetch_row()` However, you should be using all `mysqli_*` functions and will make your life a lot easier, rather than "hack away" until something gives; which it won't. You're best to find yourself a working login system.

Comment: I've followed your suggestions and it works (thanks), however it still redirects to the same page even if i am logging in as an admin.

Comment: if you can debug your code through print_r($row) exit(); after $row = $usertype->fetch_row(); check what are you getting.

Comment: Honestly, you're playing with fire using `mysql_*` functions and using plain text passwords. Tell me this is just for personal use @user3489226 If it isn't, I suggest you stop pursuing this project and find an up-to-date login system using `mysqli_*` with prepared statements or PDO and PHP's `password_hash()` function, `crypt()` or `bcrypt()` or CRYPT_BLOWFISH. You're using old and dangerous methods that will eventually bite you in the "you know what".

Answer (score 0):

you're missing a `;` in your line 31.

```
global $dbh
```

should be

```
global $dbh;
```

Comment: Not the answer to problem. You should add this as a comment

Answer (score 0):

There is a code block at the below link.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

```
<?php
/* Delete all rows from the FRUIT table */
$del = $dbh->prepare('DELETE FROM fruit');
$del->execute();

/* Return number of rows that were deleted */
print("Return number of rows that were deleted:\n");
$count = $del->rowCount();
print("Deleted $count rows.\n");
?>
```

Can you try to update your code according to this? There is different usings at the link.